# Kotlin/TeamCity environment variable to uppercase

Tags: kotlin, environment-variables, teamcity, uppercase

I want to pass the value stored in `"%env.VAR%"` to other variable in uppercase. But I'm getting `%ENV.VAR%` as result.

Tried:

```
# "%env.VAR%" = something
val var_1 = "%env.VAR%"
val var_2 = var_1.uppercase()
```

The code above returns:

```
var_2 = %ENV.VAR%
```

but I want it to be:

```
var_2 = SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was not possible. When reading teamcity environment variables in kotlin, during compilation time, they are read as literals.

That is why `"%env.VAR%".uppercase()` was returning `%ENV.VAR%`.
During the execution time, the expression `"%env.VAR%"` is read as environment variable, and `%ENV.VAR%` fails to return anything.